# How do I send a HEAD request manually using Firefox?

Tags: http, firefox, request, head

I'm debugging my webserver, and I'd like to manually send HEAD requests to some web pages. Is there a way to do this in Firefox? Some extension perhaps.

I want to use firefox so that it can be part of a normal session (ie cookies set, logged in, etc). So things like curl aren't perfect.

Comment: Do you just want to see the response headers or do you actually need to send a HEAD request?

Comment: @Chris T: I want to test my HEAD handlers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Live HTTP Headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/3829) can send arbitrary HTTP requests using its replay function.  Though it's a bit fiddly.  And as it's a HEAD request, there'll be no output to see locally (it's normally displayed in the browser window).

First you need to open up the Live HTTP Headers (LHH) window, do your request from the browser using GET, then select that request in the LHH window and choose <kbd>Replay...</kbd>.  Then, in the window that pops up, change GET to HEAD and fiddle with the headers if you like.

Pressing <kbd>Replay</kbd> will make the request.

Comment: I only saw an option for POST or GET (not HEAD) using Live HTTP Headers on FF 3.6 on windows.  So if this used to work, it doesn't now :(

Comment: Thanks for the downvote. While there's only an option for GET or POST by default in the drop-down, you can just type over those and enter whatever method you like.

Answer (score 9):

Another possiblity is opening up firebug (or making this into a greasemonkey script)  and using javascript to send your HEAD request.

```
// Added comments
 var xmlhttp = new XmlHttpRequest(); 
 xmlhttp.open("HEAD", "/test/this/page.php",true); // Make async HEAD request (must be a relative path to avoid cross-domain restrictions)
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4) { // make sure the request is complete
   alert(xmlhttp.getAllResponseHeaders()) // display the headers
  }
 }
 xmlhttp.send(null); // send request
```

XmlHttpRequests inherit the cookies and current session (authentication from .htaccess etc).

Way to use this:

- Use the javascript: url method
- Use the Firebug console (http://getfirebug.com/) to execute javascript on the page
- Create a greasemonkey script that executes HEAD requests and displays the result

Comment: If you make it so the greasemonkey script places a small div at the top of the page with a GUI such as: [textbox for url] [Send Request]. You could even re-use this for other projects and even release it

Comment: Nice answer. I guess if I can't find a simpler method, this ain't so bad.

Comment: I'm getting this error: "XmlHttpRequest is not defined", any ideas why?

Comment: Try XMLHttpRequest instead or use var xmlhttp = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new window.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty old thread, but there is a firefox plugin called "Poster" that does what you want.

There is another plugin I've used called "Rest Client" that is also good.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any plugin but this page might be of some use to you

http://www.askapache.com/online-tools/http-headers-tool

Comment: That is useful. Doesn't work on localhost though. The reason I was looking for a firefox plugin was so that I could be logged in normally etc, and would get my cookies and such right.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you can send head requests with Fiddler
http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler2/version.asp

This seems to be a solution that works in firefox as an addon, called Modify Headers
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/967

Comment: As far as I can tell, that would work. I don't have a Windows box to hand though.

Comment: Fiddler works for this (and is awesome), but only works on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Check out `http-tool` for firefox ..

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/http-tool/

```
Aimed at web developers who need to debug HTTP requests and responses.
Can be extremely useful while developing REST based api.

Features:
* GET
* HEAD
* POST
* PUT
* DELETE

Add header(s) to request.
Add body content to request.

View header(s) in response.
View body content in response.
View status code of response.
View status text of response.
```